# Concatenating Fields in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have an Excel Document that has Table Names in Column A and Column Names in Column B.

```
A1      B1
Account Account_ID
```

I can get the syntax correct.

The formula is:

```
=CONCATENATE("Select '",$A$1,"','",B1,"',",B1,", count(*) From ",$A$1, " group by '",",B1,";")
```

The output that I get is:

```
Select 'ACCOUNT','ACCOUNT_ID',ACCOUNT_ID, count(*) From ACCOUNT group by 'ACCOUNT','ACCOUNT_ID',ACCOUNT_ID;
```

The output that I need is:

```
Select 'ACCOUNT','ACCOUNT_ID',ACCOUNT_ID, count(*) From ACCOUNT group by ACCOUNT_ID;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you've shown is not what you have in the Excel workbook.

Comment: After your group by you have '",",B1,";" when you should have ", B1, ";"

Answer (score 3):

Try concatenation using the ampersand.

You can link together string literals and cell contents as such.

```
="String1" & "'" & "String2"
```

will result in

```
String1'String2
```

So to try and build sql statements from excel cells, lets say you have an excel sheet with tables and fields

```
     A        B       C
1 Table1  Column1  Column2
2 Table2  COlumn1  Column2
```

You can build sql statements from those values

```
="SELECT 'Table1', " & B1 & ", " & C1 & " FROM " & A1
="SELECT 'Table2', " & B2 & ", " & C2 & " FROM " & A2
```

Will yield

```
SELECT 'Table1', Column1, Column2 FROM Table1
SELECT 'Table2', Column1, Column2 FROM Table2
```

The quotes specify Strings and the apersand (&) joins them together. Anything outside a set of strings will be evaluated.

For example a string with a bunch of spaces could be trimmed and joined

```
= TRIM(A1) & " Trimmed"
```

would yield

```
Table1 Trimmed
```

Your particular example would look like so

```
="SELECT '" & A1 & "', '" & B1 & "', Account_ID, COUNT(*) FROM " & A1 & " GROUP BY " & B1
```

Comment: I'm having trouble because I do not know how each operator is used , " ' & etc. If I could get an explanation with an example SQL Statement that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure - revised with more info